# How do I draw a box with tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm trying to draw something like the following:

## Code for desired effect without using `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,showframe]{geometry}
%%------------------------------
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\rule{4in}{1pt}
\par
\begin{minipage}[t]{4in}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

This seems like it should be something straight-forward.  But, I'm getting lost in the documentation for `tcolorbox`.  Nothing I'm doing creates the same effect.

For example, I don't understand what the keys `interior hidden` or `enhanced` are doing or how they're interacting with each other.  Why do the following create such wildly different effects:

## First example using `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%%------------------------------
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=4in,
                  %%enhanced,
                  %%frame hidden,
                  interior hidden,
                  boxsep=0pt,
                  left=0pt,
                  right=0pt,
                  top=2pt,
                  ]%%
  \lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

produces

> [image]

## Second example using `tcolorbox`

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=4in,
                  enhanced,
                  frame hidden,
                  interior hidden,
                  boxsep=0pt,
                  left=0pt,
                  right=0pt,
                  top=2pt,
                  ]%%
  \lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
```

produces

> [image]

## Third example using `tcolorbox`

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=4in,
                  enhanced,
                  %%frame hidden,
                  interior hidden,
                  boxsep=0pt,
                  left=0pt,
                  right=0pt,
                  top=2pt,
                  ]%%
  \lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
```

produces:

> [image]

The documentation says that `interior hidden` is shorthand for

```
interior style={draw=none,fill=none}
```

but clearly `fill=none` is being ignored in the first and third examples.  Why?

I've found keys such as `enhancedfirst`, `enhancedlast`, `enhancedmiddle`, `nobeforeafter`.  But none of these achieve the effects that I want in terms of framing:  I just want a bar across the top of the box.

Additional issues:

1. The text is formatted differently between the `minipage` environment approach and the `tcolorbox` environment even though the widths are the same.
2. There's a sliver of white space along the left hand side (and who knows where else) that I can't seem to get rid of from the `tcolorbox` environment.

Could someone please show me how to set up a `tcolorbox` enivornment to get the effect I want?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need `boxrule=0pt` and `toprule` commands.

```
boxrule=0pt,toprule=1pt,
```

Similarly there are `bottomrule` `leftrule` and `\rightrule`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%%------------------------------
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=4in,
                  boxsep=0pt,
                  left=0pt,
                  right=0pt,
                  top=2pt,
                  arc=0pt,
                  boxrule=0pt,toprule=1pt,
                  colback=white
                  ]%%
  \lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I copy your example, I still get faint vestiges of the frame.  Any ideas why?

Comment: @A.Ellett Viewer issues. Try with adobe or some thing else.

Comment: @A.Ellett I agree to Harish Kumar, it is a previewer problem. If you add the key `enhanced jigsaw` to the given code, `SumatraPDF` and `Adobe Reader` for Windows show a cleaner output. Other viewers on other systems may react differently to the change.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the outer box in tcolormode?